# System running very slow

Tags: boot, 18.04, 20.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04 . It was working smooth but suddenly it became very slow.  After clicking on one button it takes almost 5-10 seconds to open that file. So I decided to install ubuntu 20.04 but the installation process is also taking too much time.

Comment: did you see the memory usage any background processes running?

Comment: Yes i did,  and have killed some process many times but that didn't help.

Comment: You've provided almost no details so how can we know.  Are there signs of thrashing? Is your box ram challenged? have swap available?  What applications are you talking about? What else is running?  Have you checked your hardware (drive health comes to mind - I'd check this out using *live* media and not the installed system), is the box hot?  cpu hot?  (as some CPUs throttle down speed as they reach temperature threshold.. did you explore any of this??)  You've provided almost no details for us to offer suggestions on...  shat you've explored, what you've ruled out etc, or details of your box